# GCM - How to add again all devices when server went down?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

My app call a webservice on my server to store all the device registrationID in a DB. When my gcm-server crashes and/or goes down, I have to re-import all registrationID which are in my DB...

How can I do that avoiding a very large loop to re-fill the Datastore class ?

Thanks :)

Comment: if your app generate new id widhing 15 day for perticular user?? then no need to so this. if id not found on server then it again try for new registration. so your problem is aolved automatically..

Comment: I think the obvious and only solution is to keep your backups up to date.

Comment: Dhaval - And if we want to push users who aren't come back again in my app ? No new registration => No push to this user

Comment: why would server crash affect DB's data? wouldn't restart the server solve the problem?